# Can PDF format support raster images placed in separate layers?

Tags: image, pdf, export, raster, layer

I would like to know if it is possible to render 3D shaded objects from CAD to raster images and arrange them in separate layers in a pdf file, so that I can turn off the visibility of individual objects in pdf?
If no, can you explain me why it is not possible?

[image]

Comment: Just imagine 3 lit cubes - red one is on left, green one is on right and blue one is in the middle. There are 3 layers named "test1" , "test2" and "test3". When I check on/off checkbox near layer named "test1" raster image with left red cube become visible/invisible etc.  How is it implemented? Has pdf operators to set raster image coordinates?
[Desired.png](https://postimg.cc/Mnh62KKS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF has Optional Content Groups. For a very simple case it can work well in Adobe graphics products, and a few others, but layer support is not good in all PDF viewers. Thus layers and OCG methods are to be avoided for any wider consumption. Using layered images usually involves transparency/translucency masking thus also exceptionally difficult to control where overlaid.

Images can be attached or set as layers so here I have switched the green block off, You will find limitations with using layers for image control if the images are overlaid, but it is not impossible to place the 3 in one location.

[image]
[image]
[image]

***Avoid placing readable/searchable text on layers (sometimes suggested for presentation or alternate languages) It will be a nightmare for both audio and impaired visual readers that have limited layer controls.***